# Resetting GRBL command not working in arduino IDE serial monitor

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-ide, cnc

I am testing Grbl CNC Shield with my Arduino Uno. Everything is working except for the ctrl-x command. I tried on the Arduino IDE serial monitor but it appears that it dont recognize.

Does anyone how to solve this?
Any help would be appreciated.

I Tried:
Holding Ctrl with x and nothing happend.
sending ^X or ^x but the console responded "Error: Excepted command Letter"
sending 0x18 on the console and it responded "Error: Bad Number Format"

When the reset command is triggered and it's in the Alarm lock it should reset the grbl and show that message again. This would happen too if the grbl is running normally

Answer (score 0):

```
cnc_ard = serial.Serial('COM11',115200)
y= "\n" #(ctrl-x)
cnc_ard.write(y.encode())
```

[image]

Here is what I did with Python. Open cmd from there just press ctrl + x. It will come there^X. After entering it will show there . From there copy this inside note+. It will come there "CAN" like this. Copy that and enter this in Serial monitor. Please check these pictures attached below.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

in python the comand 0x18 is b'\x18'

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).